# Bootstrap 3 modal not working on button click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I made a simple modal following a tutorial and when I click the button the modal does not show up. I tried changing `href` to `data-target` but that din't fix the problem. The code below is the modal code. I have nothing in my CSS or JavaScript file.

```
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>Sign up for weekly newsletter</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up for the newsletter</h4>
                    <div class=modal-body>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here's a CodePen: http://codepen.io/jordanbaron123/pen/pbamPa

Comment: Can we see your button code?

Comment: @CharlieFish I added it.

Comment: Do you have bootstrap JS included or just the CSS? I forget if it makes a difference for modals. I know it does for certain things. I think you need it for modals tho.

Comment: Yeah, I have the Bootstrap JS.

Comment: Can you try changing the a tag to a button tag? It does need to be data-target but I think data-target only works on buttons.

Comment: I changed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I personally can't see any other issues with it then. Any chance you can send us a link to an example? Or like a codepen or something like that of what your trying to do?

Comment: I made a codepen. http://codepen.io/jordanbaron123/pen/pbamPa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your head you need to have the following. Also remove the bootstrap links at the bottom of your body. Looks to me like you might have been running an outdated version of bootstrap js.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/fishcharlie/pen/pbamWL) as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put the modal html in the root of the html , probably immediate after the body tag. It could be placed on the bottom of all html , but as immediate nested element of the body or one div after that.

Modal html works with immediate nesting of these following :

- body>div>modal html
- body>modal html

Then it will work. Otherwise if the modal html is placed inside many nested elements then it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle instead data-toggle and data-target since this is the newest bootstrap syntax I am sure this gonna fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).